Elasticsearch 8 Docker image with data pre-loaded from snapshot
I was intending to ask for help on this but I have now got it working by the following (somewhat long-winded) route, which may or may not be the best way but others may find it useful or wish to comment.
Create a snapshot-enabled ES cluster in your local docker using a compose file similar to the one below:
version: '3'
services:
  es:
    image: europe-west2-docker.pkg.dev/ons-ci-aims/aims-api-demo/elasticsearch-aims-8.15.3
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster-one
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled=false
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled=false
      - "path.repo=/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/snapshots"
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"

Next, create an empty directory on your local machine and copy your snapshot to it. The exact command depends on where the snapshot is stored, the example below is for a GCS bucket:
gsutil -m cp -r gs://my-test-index-bucket/* .

Now copy the snapshot to the data directory of the Elasticsearch cluster in Docker.
docker cp . elasticsearch:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/snapshots

Now you can use Cerebro or Kibana to restore the index, command to create the repository below:
PUT _snapshot/snapshots
{
  "type": "fs",
  "settings": { "location": "/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/snapshots", "compress": true }
}

Next step is to use commit to make a new image from the running image
docker ps -a  (get image id, lets say it's abc12345)
docker commit abc12345 elasticsearch-loaded-8.15.3-temp

Finally create a Dockerfile as below to remove the lock files
FROM elasticsearch-loaded-8.15.3-temp
RUN rm -f /usr/share/elasticsearch/data/node.lock
RUN rm -f /usr/share/elasticsearch/data/write.lock
RUN rm -f /usr/share/elasticsearch/data/snapshot_cache/write.lock

Build
docker build . --tag elasticsearch-loaded-8.15.3

Tag and push as required.

...what's your question?  You mention docker commit in the text, but this is almost never a best practice (how do you upgrade the Elasticsearch instance to fix some future security issue, without losing the embedded data?).
